# How to FIX zero(0) username on mysql

Tags: java, android

This my problem, every time I try to register, MySQL inputs an username field of  "0". Here is my table:

[MySQL Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CNGh.png)

**RegisterActivity.class**

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.app.laundry.crudtest1.Help.RegisterRequest;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        final EditText etAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAge);
        final EditText etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        final EditText etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        final EditText etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        final Button bRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);

        bRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String name = etName.getText().toString();
                final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
                final int age = Integer.parseInt(etAge.getText().toString());
                final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

                Response.Listener<String responseListener = new Response.Listener<String() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                            if (success) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                                RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                            } else {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                                builder.setMessage("Register Failed")
                                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                        .create()
                                        .show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };

                RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(name, username, age, password, responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);
                queue.add(registerRequest);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**RegisterRequest.class**

```
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;    
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class RegisterRequest extends StringRequest {
    private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "http://10.0.2.2/ai/Register.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public RegisterRequest(String name, String username, int age, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
        super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("name", name);
        params.put("age", age + "");
        params.put("username", username);
        params.put("password", password);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

**Register.php**

```
<?php
     $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "ae");

     $name = $_POST["name"];
     $age = $_POST["age"];
     $username = $_POST["username"];
     $password = $_POST["password"];

     $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user (name, username, age, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
     mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $name, $username, $age, $password);
     mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

     $response = array();
     $response["success"] = true;  

     echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

**Rester2.php**

```
<?php
   require("password.php");

   $connect = mysqli_connect("my_host", "my_user", "my_password", "my_database");

   $name = $_POST["name"];
   $age = $_POST["age"];
   $username = $_POST["username"];
   $password = $_POST["password"];

    function registerUser() {
       global $connect, $name, $age, $username, $password;
       $passwordHash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
       $statement = mysqli_prepare($connect, "INSERT INTO user (name, age, username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
       mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $name, $age, $username, $passwordHash);
       mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
       mysqli_stmt_close($statement);     
   }

   function usernameAvailable() {
       global $connect, $username;
       $statement = mysqli_prepare($connect, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?"); 
       mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $username);
       mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
       mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
       $count = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($statement);
       mysqli_stmt_close($statement);
   }

   $response = array();
   $response["success"] = false;  

   if (usernameAvailable()){
       registerUser();
       $response["success"] = true;  
   }

   echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: What is the value of `etUsername.getText()`? (And why are you converting a string to a string?)

Comment: And you should not write a separate SELECT statement to test whether the username is available prior to the INSERT. You should just attempt the INSERT and handle the  uniqueness violation if and when it happens. You need to do this kind of thing atomically, otherwise you are building in timing-window problems.

Comment: @EJP i just follow instruction tutorial login register from youtube, can you help me please

Comment: *What do you mean* 'can you help me'? That is exactly what I am trying to do here. But I can't do any more than I have until you answer the questions you're asked.

Comment: yes i know, i'm sorry for that .. i'm replay you comment before you comment this "  
And you should not write a separate SELECT statement to test whether the username is available prior to the INSERT. You should just attempt the INSERT and handle the uniqueness violation if and when it happens. You need to do this kind of thing atomically, otherwise you are building in timing-window problems." and after i'm replay you comment, the notif emerging @EJP

Comment: I don't understand a word of that, but asking questions is also trying to help you, and not answering them and complaining is just offensive behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

In Register.php, it shoule be `ssis`

```
 $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user (name, username, age, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ssis", $name, $username, $age, $password);
```

Just a typo, in RegisterActivity class, it should be

```
Response.Listener<String> responseListener
```

EDIT: The string `siss` means `string int string string`. So, it gave you value `0` for the integer. Changing to `ssss`, i.e. `string string string string`, fixes it.

Comment: You should explain why, i.e. that `s` means string, `i` means integer, etc.

Comment: Thanks you, I edited and gave my opinion.

Comment: @GAVD So many many thankyou, its work for me, thank you so much sir for your answer

Comment: Fixed your edit. Nobody is interested in guesswork.

Comment: your answer very helpfully, once again thanks you @GAVD

Comment: @JetliMoslem you are welcome!

Comment: thanks for any advice from you, I hope I get feedback (advice) from your @EJP